How can I project dynamic filter chips using `ng-template`, `ngTemplateOutlet`, and `ng-content` in Angular?
I'm working on an Angular application where I need to build a reusable filter bar component that displays dynamic filter chips based on user selections. The filter chips need to be projected into the filter bar using ng-template, ngTemplateOutlet, and ng-content. Additionally, I need to emit an event when a chip is closed.
Current Implementation:
I have a parent component (MyComponent) that tracks active filters in an array called activeFilters. Each filter has a label, value, and key. The parent component passes these filters to the FilterBarComponent using content projection.
Here's the structure:
Parent Component (MyComponent):
<app-filter-bar 
  [hasActiveFilters]="activeFilters.length > 0" 
  (clearAll)="clearAllFilters()">
  <!-- Project filter chips using ng-template and ngTemplateOutlet -->
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="filterChipTemplate; context: { $implicit: activeFilters, close: onChipClose.bind(this) }"></ng-container>
</app-filter-bar>

<!-- Template for the filter chips -->
<ng-template #filterChipTemplate let-filters let-close="close">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let filter of filters">
    <app-filter-chip 
      [label]="filter.label" 
      [value]="filter.value" 
      [filterKey]="filter.key" 
      (close)="close(filter.key)">
    </app-filter-chip>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>

FilterBarComponent:
<div class="filter-bar">
  <!-- Clear All Filters link -->
  <a href="#" 
     class="clear-all-filters" 
     (click)="clearAllFilters()" 
     [class.disabled]="!hasActiveFilters">
    Clear All Filters
  </a>

  <!-- Projected Filter Chips -->
  <div class="filter-chips-container">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>

FilterChipComponent:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter-chip',
  template: `
    <div class="chip">
      <span>{{ label }}: {{ value }}</span>
      <button (click)="close.emit(filterKey)">x</button>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./filter-chip.component.css']
})
export class FilterChipComponent {
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() filterKey: string;
  @Output() close = new EventEmitter<string>();
}

Problem:
I’m using a ng-template with ngTemplateOutlet in the parent component to generate the filter chips dynamically. The chips are projected into the FilterBarComponent via ng-content. However, I'm concerned about how this setup will render multiple filter chips (e.g., 4 filters) since I only have a single ng-content in the child component.
Question:

Is this approach correct in the first place?
How does Angular handle projecting multiple components when only one ng-content is used?
Is there a better or more efficient way to handle this situation to ensure the chips render properly and the event bindings work as expected?

Example Scenario:
Assume I have the following activeFilters array in my parent component:
activeFilters = [
  { label: 'Category', value: 'Books', key: 'category' },
  { label: 'Author', value: 'John Doe', key: 'author' },
  { label: 'Price', value: '$10-$20', key: 'price' },
  { label: 'Rating', value: '4+ stars', key: 'rating' }
];

Thank you in advance for your help!

Your approach of using content projection with ng-template, ngTemplateOutlet, and ng-content valid but overly complicated.
You can simply use the <app-filter-chip> directly in your template:
<app-filter-bar 
  [hasActiveFilters]="activeFilters.length > 0" 
  (clearAll)="clearAllFilters()">

    <app-filter-chip *ngFor="let filter of filters"
      [label]="filter.label" 
      [value]="filter.value" 
      [filterKey]="filter.key" 
      (close)="close(filter.key)"
    />
</app-filter-bar>

This will accomplish the same result, with simpler template.

How does Angular handle projecting multiple components when only one ng-content is used?

Angular's ng-content will project all content from the parent component into the child component at the location of the ng-content tag. This means that even if you have multiple filter chips, they will all be projected into the single ng-content in your FilterBarComponent. You don't need separate ng-content tags for each chip; in fact, Angular only allows a single <ng-content> element (without a selector) per template.

Got it, Thank you for taking time . So I tried with your approach at first but got derailed went into the rabbit hole of content projection missed out on how this can be resolved easily.  Another solution also worked for me which is mentioned here in this article. link
